# How to combine @JsonView with @JsonProperty?

Tags: json, spring-mvc, jackson

I have a DTO class that should serve `json` via a `spring-mvc` `@RestController`.

I want to provide different version/views on the same object. Especially, there are fields that are only used in `VERSION_1` of the api, and some only in `VERSION_2`.

Problem: I could add `@JsonView` for this, but my goal is also to rename those fields. Some fields should actually **replace** the same name from previous versions.

Example:

```
public class Person {
    @JsonView(View.Version_1.class)
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name; //eg only the firstname

    @JsonView(View.Version_2.class)
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private NameDTO namedto; //now changing to first+last name

    static class NameDTO {
       private String firstname;
       private String lastname;
    }
}

@RestController 
public class MyServlet {
    @GetMapping("/person/{id}")
    @JsonView(View.Version_1.class)
    public PersonDTO person1(int id) {
        //...
    }

    @GetMapping("/person_new/{id}")
    @JsonView(View.Version_2.class)
    public PersonDTO person2(int id) {
        //...
    }
}
```

So, depending on the view/version, you would get the same json field `firstname`, but with different content.

In this example, using V1 would give:

`{"name": "john"}`

Whereas using V2 should result in:

`{"name": {"firstname": "john", "lastname": "doe"}}`

BUT not with he code above, as jackson complains:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Conflicting
>   getter definitions for property "name".

Is that possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way using: 
https://github.com/jonpeterson/spring-webmvc-model-versioning

Basic idea is to add a custom `VersionedModelConverter` that is applied on `@VersionedModelConverter` annotated webservice response classes.

```
@Configuration
@Import(VersionedModelResponseBodyAdvice.class)
public class SpringMvcVersioningConfiguration {
   //register in jackson. spring-boot automatically registers any module beans
   @Bean
   public Model versioningModel() {
       return new VersioningModule();
   }
}

@GetMapping
@VersionedResponseBody(defaultVersion = "2.0")
public Person person() {
}

@JsonVersionedModel(currentVersion = "3.0"  toPastConverterClass = PersonConverter.class)
public class Person {
}

public class PersonConverter implements VersionedModelConverter {
    @Override
    public ObjectNode convert(ObjectNode modelData, String modelVersion, String targetModelVersion, JsonNodeFactory nodeFactory) {
        Double modelv = Double.valueOf(modelVersion);
        Double targetv = Double.valueOf(targetVersion);
        //todo if-else based on model version

        Object node = modelData.remove("fieldname");
        //node.change...
        modelData.set("fieldname_renamed", node);
    }
}
```